# How to open a file in the user's default program on button click with tkinter?

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, tkinter

Can you please suggest how to open a file in the user's default program on button click with python's tkinter?

Comment: What should be a "users default program" ?

Comment: VLC media player, for example

Comment: `os.startfile('path.mp4')` i assume it will open for the default program itself

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. You should try to give more information with your questions. What steps are you taking? What have you tried? Are there some error messages that appear? Also, try adding a bit of code to make your point, or add a link to an external site with an example of your issue. It will improve your chances of being answered.

Comment: Thank you guys! The comment from Cool Cloud was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think that problem occures because that file you are trying to open is not in the same folder as the program you are trying to run. If it is not in same folder you need to put whole path but I recomend you to make folder every time you are making new project and then put all files, images, text documents ect. you will need in that folder.